# How Can I Get This PHP Registration Script To Redirect To Profile Page Based On User ID?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to redirect each user to a dedicated "**userinfo.php**" after successful registration, but the browser terminates the redirection because it goes into endless loops.

I need your help, please. Thanks.

The following is section of the "**register.php**" that has redirect:

```
<?php

    // include configuration file
    require ("includes/config.php");
        
            try
            {   
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username, email, phone FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR phone = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$username, $email, $phone]);
            $user = $stmt->fetch(); # get users data
            
            if($user["username"]==$username)
            {
                 $usernameErr="Sorry username already exists"; //check condition username already exists
            }
            else if($user["email"]==$email)
            {
                $emailErr="Sorry email already exists"; //check condition email already exists 
            }
            else if($user["phone"]==$phone)
            {
                 $phoneErr="Sorry, the phone number already exists"; //check condition email already exists 
            }
            else //check no "$error" shows, then continue
            {
                $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //encrypt password using password_hash()

               // insert form input into database           
           $stmt=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, gender, password, email, birthday, phone, regdate, userimage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
          $stmt->execute([$firstname, $lastname, $username, $gender, $new_password, $email, $birthday, $phone, $imagename]);
                
               // find out user's ID
           $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS user_id");
               $stmt->execute();
               $user_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
            
               // redirect to list users page
               header("Location: userinfo.php?id=".$user_id);
            }
         }
                catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }       
    
}
        // render the header template
        include("templates/header.php");
        
        // render add user template
        include("templates/register-form.php");
    
       // render the footer template
       include("templates/footer.php");
?>
```

My intention is that if a non-logged in user requests for any page, other than "**admin/login.php**", "**admin/logout.php**", and "**admin/register.php**", the person will be redirected to "admin/login.php".

Moreover, I want if a non-logged in user requests for any page in the front-end, except "**login.php**", "**logout.php**", and "**register.php**", the person will be redirected to "login.php".

I do have the following redirect code in the "**config.php**", which I suspect is causing the issue:

```
// require authentication for most pages
if (!preg_match("{(admin/login|logout|register)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{
   if (empty($_SESSION["aid"]))
    {
       header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
if (!preg_match("{(?:index|login|logout|register)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{
    if (empty($_SESSION["user_id"]))
    {
       header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just have a database entry for last login. And if last login == NULL (first login) then redirect, otherwise you can track their login for future use.

Comment: @Mech, Is there a simpler way to redirect via PHP, without adding a new table column to hold last login.

Comment: @Justin, the question about security is another question and is too broad. Removing it, will help to focus answers to redirection question.

Comment: @Justin also, if you can supply a shorter and more specific code that reproduce the redirect problem. It can help experts understand your problem and encourage answers.

Comment: @amotzg, a million thanks; I've heeded your advice and I hope the code looks more specific now.

Comment: @Justin, in my opinion, the database entry is the simpler way. And it creates another control for administration (purge old accounts/entice users to come back/establish their first log in/etc).

Comment: @Mech, I guess the last_login database entry should be of which type? "date" or "datetime" or "timestamp"? Does it have to auto_increment?

Comment: I would use unix timestamp. 1595446622 converts to 07/22/2020 @ 7:37pm (UTC). Keep it simple in the database and parse it to be human readable only when needed (which would be rare). I like https://www.epochconverter.com/ for this as it will tell you how to get the current unix time in a number of different programming languages, including SQL. I would just add a quick `UPDATE` query to the page when a user logs in to keep the data relevant.

Comment: @Mech, thanks for your insight.